# How does golang create a buffer to pass to a C dll function?

Tags: go

I need to invoke a C API from golang, which is from a dll.
The problem is the C func need a buffer, how to create the 
buffer in golang, then i can pass the buffer to the C func?

```
void fooGetString(char* buffer, int buffer length)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
s := make([]byte, 256)
C.fooGetString((*C.char)(unsafe.Pointer(&s[0])), C.int(len(s)))
```

Comment: I forgot to comment here originally, but I updated this answer so that it is correct, as it was marked as the correct answer.

Answer (score 5):

```
package main

// #include <string.h>
// void foo(char *s, int len) {
//     strncpy(s, "foo", len);
// }
import "C"

import "fmt"
import "unsafe"

func main() {
    buf := make([]byte, 256)
    C.foo((*C.char)(unsafe.Pointer(&buf[0])), C.int(len(buf)))
    fmt.Println(string(buf))
}
```

Output:

```
foo
```